# Bootstrap-select Live Search is not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a big list of players and when a user is searching for a particular one I would like that only found players were showing.

I'm using in this case bootstrap-select. This is my code of different drop-down select. It uses data-live-search,but still doesn't work:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-size="7" data-style="btn btn-default btn-round" name="method" id="method" title="Select sign up method" data-live-search="true" required>
     <option value="" selected>- Select sign up method -</option>
     <option value="2yes">Both players ARE system users</option>
     <option value="1yes1no">You ARE system user, but partner is NOT</option>
     <option value="1yes">You ARE system user (for singles)</option>
</select>
```

So select menu works fine, but live-search doesn't work. There is a field for a search, but functionality (probably css) is not working at all.

Header includes:

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
```

Footer:

```
<script src="assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-selectpicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Demo you can check [here](https://beachtennis.io/tournament.php?title=RIGA_NEW_YEAR%27S_CUP&id=2) (Sign up for tournament -> choose a method)

Comment: Why didn't you create an minimal runable example, that shows your problem? I am quite sure most of all users here don't want to sign up just for reproducing an problem.

Comment: Nobody needs to sign up ) It's under "sign up" accordion

Comment: hey can you mark the answer as correct if it helped you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove error thrown in the console first

> slick.js:25 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>       at slick.js:25
>       at slick.js:28

Then you need to including `bootstrap.js` and `cs` files see demo below, and on your site, i cant find the `bootstrap-select.css` included in the source.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<div class="bs-docs-example no-code">
  <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
    <option>Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
    <option>Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
    <option>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
  </select>
</div>
```